# Akka HTTP Testkit: How to write test case of Akka HTTP Websocket

Tags: java, scala, websocket, junit4, akka-http

I am writing a Akka HTTP WebSocket routes with `Java`. But unable to find the way for testing WebSocket with Java. There is no documentation or samples are available in akka. Following is my java websocket code:

```
public final Route connectRoute(){
    return path("connect", () -> handleWebSocketMessages(greetings()));
}

private static Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greetings(){
    return Flow.<Message>create().collect(new JavaPartialFunction<Message, Message>() {
        @Override
        public Message apply(Message msg, boolean isCheck) throws Exception {
            if(isCheck){
                if(msg.isText()) return null;
                else throw noMatch();
            }else{
                return handleTextMessage(msg.asTextMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

private static TextMessage handleTextMessage(TextMessage msg) {
    if(msg.isStrict()){
        return TextMessage.create("Hello "+msg.getStrictText());
    }else{
        return TextMessage.create(Source.single("Hello ").concat(msg.getStreamedText()));
    }
}
```

Akka HTTP have client web socket library also, but this is not the way for testing websockets. In scala, [this sample is available.](https://github.com/knoldus/akka-http-websocket-microservices/blob/master/api/src/test/scala/com/knoldus/server/WebServerTest.scala) How can i create test case with Java?

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. Did you find something out?

Comment: hey @DiegoMartinoia no, still not found any solution

Comment: It may not be clean, but I just gave up and in the tests I instantiate the whole server and bind to the actual ports of the machine and use those. Truly end to end.